# Why can a directed line segment be called a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was reviewing some of the formal definitions of linear algebra and I found this issue. I particularly have difficulty with formalizing some of the more "trivial" definitions and theorems, so maybe this has something to do with that.

A vector is an equivalence class, which is a set, then why can we say that a particular oriented line segment is a vector? Is it just abuse of notation and we should call it a representative of such set? Or is it because the vector is well defined by just one of the oriented line segments in the equivalence class?

Comment: Yes and yes to both your questions.

Comment: It would be useful to know what text you are working out of.  The definition you have given looks like the kind of informal definition that is usually given in very introductory linear algebra classes... is that the kind of class you are taking / reading for?

Comment: See [Vectors in Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)#Vectors_in_Euclidean_geometry): "In classical Euclidean geometry, vectors were introduced  as equivalence classes, under equipollence, of ordered pairs of points." An "ordered pair of points" is an *oriented segment*.